# Including a study with an opposite outcome direction in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, meta-regression

I have a study whose outcome measure runs opposite to that in the rest of the studies in my study pool (with this one: `the lower the outcome the better`, with others: `the higher the outcome the better`).

If I only consider the mean differences between Narrative 2 and Narrative 1 within each group, then the "Experimental" group ($mean.dif = .0331$) has achieved a lower outcome (thus the better one) compared to the "Control" group ($mean.dif = .0332$).

However, if I compute an effect size within each group between Narrative 2 and Narrative 1, then the  "Experimental" group ($es = .82$; thus the worse one) is higher than that of the  "Control" group  ($es = .74$ ; thus the better one).

**(1)** Which index ($mean.dif$ or $es$) can tell me which group has performed better (has achieved a lower outcome)?

**(2)** The current signs of the effect sizes must be reversed, if they want to join the rest of the study pool, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the standardised mean difference (unless they are all commensurate scales). As you have worked out the effect size measure is useless in this context if direction of difference is important.

You simply reverse the sign of the differences where appropriate. The standard errors are unaffected of course.

Comment: To be clear, the result of this experiment shows that Experimental group's performance is worse than that of the control group, right?

Comment: I was offering general advice about the situation. I am afraid there is not enough detail about the study you quote to offer specific advice.

Comment: Would you please let me know what additional detail you would want to know? Thanks